# How to make a space between section's number and the title

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I was so confused of thinking about this. I'm trying to make a space between the section number and the text after it. I want to make a chapter as illustrated below. I have no idea about this because I'm using my own class and don't know where to edit.
[image]

here's the section settings on my class

```
% SECTION  
%  
% Section names are bold face typed using \bf.
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%  
\refstepcounter{section}  
\noindent
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\bf\thesection\space\space{#1}}%
\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize         % IF it is longer than one line, use indentation
%    \vskip 1pt \noindent\ssp \hangindent 0.36in
\vskip 1pt \noindent\ssp \hangindent 0.33in  
{\bf\thesection\space\space{#1}\par} \dsp
\else                              % ELSE  center.
{\bf\thesection\space\space{#1}}
\fi
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect
    \makebox[.15cm][r]{\thesection} \hspace*{3pt}#1}
}

% SUBSECTION
%
% Subsection names are typed italic bold, and they are not included in tha table of contents.
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{subsection}
\noindent
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\bf\thesubsection\space\space{#1}}%
 \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize         % IF it is longer than one line, use indentation
%    \vskip 1pt \noindent\ssp \hangindent 0.36in
     \vskip 1pt \noindent\ssp \hangindent 0.49in  
  {\bf\thesubsection\space\space{#1}\par} \dsp
  \else                              % ELSE  center.
  {\bf\thesubsection\space\space{#1}}
  \fi
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect
%___________________________________________
%  {\textbf{\thesubsection\space\space{#1}}}
%  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-10pt}}
%  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect
%  \makebox[0.3in][r]{\thesubsection.} \hspace*{3pt}#1}
   \makebox[.2mm][r]{\thesubsection} \hspace*{3pt}#1}
   }


% SUBSUBSECTION
% Subsubsection names are typed italic,and they are not included in the table of contents.
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{subsubsection}
\noindent
{\text{\thesubsubsection\space\space{#1}}}
%  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-10pt}}
%  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect
%  \makebox[0.3in][r]{\thesubsubsection.} \hspace*{3pt}#1}
}
```

Note: \dsp defined as double spacing, ans \ssp defined as single spacing

Comment: please show your current definition of the section titles, preferably with a small complete test document. It is impossible to tell you how to adjust code we can not see.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've make some changes. Thanks for reminding me

Comment: why are you not using any of the latex facilities for defining section heads? Also presumably your class defined `\bf` somewhere as latex does not define it. No one can run the code as posted which makes it very hard to suggest any changes or test answers, please provide a small test document that uses these definitions and has all needed macros defined.